# C++ vector reference works funny

Tags: c++, vector, stl, pass-by-reference

I have written a simple c++ algorithm to calculate permutations of a vector. The below code works fine if I change this 13. line

```
vector<int>& pp = p.front();
```

to this

```
vector<int> pp = p.front();
```

I cannot understand why. I don`t think it is caused by reallocation. Could someone explain?

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    void f(vector<vector<int> >& p, vector<int>& num)
    {
        if (p.front().size() == num.size()) return;
        int k = p.size();
        while (k)
        {
            vector<int>& pp = p.front();
            for (int toAdd : num)
            {
                bool found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < pp.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (pp[i] == toAdd)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    vector<int> newp;
                    for (int i = 0; i < pp.size(); i++)
                    {
                        newp.push_back(pp[i]);
                    }
                    newp.push_back(toAdd);
                    p.push_back(newp);
                }
            }
            p.erase(p.begin());
            k--;
        }
        f(p, num);
    }

    vector<vector<int> > permute(vector<int> &num)
    {
        vector<vector<int>> r;
        r.reserve(2 << num.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
        {
            r.push_back(vector<int>());
            r[i].push_back(num[i]);
        }
        f(r, num);
        return r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    vector<int> num{ 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, -1 };
    auto a = s.permute(num);
    a.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you think  it could be caused by re-allocation?

Comment: Don't hold onto references or pointers to items in a vector, and especially if you're increasing the number of elements in a vector.

Comment: `I have written a simple c++ algorithm to calculate permutations of a vector`  There is `std::next_permuation` for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"?

Comment: You should attempt to simplify the code, and see what might be failing. For example, the loop that updates `found` looks like a call to `std::find`, the loop inside `if (!found)` is just `vector<int> newp(pp)`...

Comment: @juanchopanza because I thought I was reserving enough memory, but in fact it was not enough memory. So you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of this statement:

```
p.push_back(newp)
```

That invalidates all references to entries in the vector `p`, *because* it can reallocate the contents.

Comment: But `pp` isn't being used after the call to `push_back()`, so why would iterator invalidation cause the problem?

Comment: @templateboy How do we know that? What if the loop continues?

Comment: `pp` only exists for the scope of the loop, so the reference only exists *that* long.

Comment: @templateboy Because push_back needs to reallocate the internal buffer for the new element. The old element is no longer valid nor the reference to it.

Comment: @templateboy The `push_back` is inside a `for` loop, what if that loop continues after the `push_back`?

Comment: You are definitely right. Thank you very much. I thought this line was allocating enough memory

    r.reserve(2 << num.size());

but it was not enough.